# Storing data from JSON object received from Google People Api

Tags: javascript, json, google-people-api

So I have a server that receives data from Google People api regarding contacts and my received object has the following structure:

```
{ connections:
[ { resourceName: 'people/c3904925882068251400',
   etag: '%EgYBAgkLNy4aDQECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0iDFZUOUE0NkRBZW0wPQ==',
   names:
    [ { metadata: { primary: true, source: [Object] },
        displayName: 'Mihai Vrincut',
        familyName: 'Vrincut',
        givenName: 'Mihai',
        displayNameLastFirst: 'Vrincut, Mihai' },
      { metadata: { source: [Object] },
        displayName: 'Mihai Vrincut',
        familyName: 'Vrincut',
        givenName: 'Mihai',
        displayNameLastFirst: 'Vrincut, Mihai' } ],
   emailAddresses:
    [ { metadata: { primary: true, source: [Object] },
        value: 'mihai.vrincut@gmail.com' } ] },
 { resourceName: 'people/c3275206487406036814',
   etag: '%EgYBAgkLNy4aDQECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0iDHBFVzBUMm8wWU5nPQ==',
   names:
    [ { metadata: { primary: true, source: [Object] },
        displayName: 'aaaaaaaaa',
        givenName: 'aaaaaaaaa',
        displayNameLastFirst: 'aaaaaaaaa' } ] },
 { resourceName: 'people/c5777943907795350059',
   etag: '%EgYBAgkLNy4aDQECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0iDGxOeGYwblg3bFUwPQ==',
   names:
    [ { metadata: { primary: true, source: [Object] },
        displayName: 'costin',
        givenName: 'costin',
        phoneticFamilyName: 'cancius',
        phoneticGivenName: 'costin',
        displayNameLastFirst: 'costin' } ],
   emailAddresses: [ { metadata: { primary: true, source: [Object] }, value: 'hj' } ],
   phoneNumbers:
    [ { metadata: { primary: true, source: [Object] },
        value: '07543532512',
        canonicalForm: '+40754353251' } ] } ], totalPeople: 3}totalItems: 3 }
```

In order to get this object I used the util.inspect() method. However, when I try to access the names for example, I get undefined:

```
var response=util.inspect(responses,{depth:5}); 
Console.log(response.connections[0].names);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What do you get if you log response.connections[0]?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: What about console.log(response)?

Comment: Please add the complete http request in your question

Comment: Gives the output that I have posted in the question.

Comment: You probably didn't convert the response to JSON object, do console.log(typeof response)

Comment: var response=util.inspect(responses,{depth:5});

Comment: The type of response is string. How do I convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, given the situation, and the information you've given over the comment sections.
I assume that responses is already an object, but util.inspect, makes it a string with a JSON kind of syntax but without the quotes (") before and after the names of the keys. That's why you get

> { connections: ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 2

So, try going over the responses object.

```
console.log(responses)
```

And get the name of the keys. With them

```
console.log(responses.sth.sthElse.anotherSth.anotherSthElse.lastSth.connections)
```

And see if you get the expected result :)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the response to JSON Object.
try this:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(response).connections[0].names);
```

(I am assuming you are working in Javascript)

Comment: { connections: 
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 2

Comment: What if you avoid the util.inspect? Try parsing "responses" first

Comment: [object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: You need to go over the responses obj until you get to connections

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is validate if the answer is a String, you have a

```
console.log (typeof response)
```

if it is a string, convert it to JSON:

```
let responseObject = JSON.parse (response);
```

Finally, try if you can access the object:

```
console.log (responseObject.connections [0] .names);
```

You tell me your answer :)

Comment: I get  { connections: 
  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 2

Comment: console.log (typeof response)  ==> and what did he return to the console?

Comment: response was string

Comment: the answer to your problem raised at the beginning is like a string of text and not an object or array, that's why it gives you an error.

Try converting it with this function:
    let responseObject = JSON.parse (response);

Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Then do this:
    console.log (responseObject);

You tell me what was the result in the console. (Y)